# Limitar el numero de resultados de una relacion con el ORM de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo una relacion de muchos a muchos con una tabla de Categorias y Business y quiero obtener las categorias mas visitadas junto con los Business relacionados a la categoria pero solo quiero traer los primeros 5 registros de Business.

Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera:

** Estoy usando repositorios y  **$this = Category::class**

```
return $this->with(['businesses' => function ($query) {
       $query->orderBy('views', 'desc')->take(10);
    }])
        ->orderBy('views', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

lo he intentado tambien con `take()`, agregandole el `get()` al final y tambien poniendo `return` al principio pero solo me regresa 1 resultado, si quito el `take()` me regresa 55 resultados. HELP y de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

- En tu consulta si quieres tomar solo a los 5 primeros puedes axuliarte `take()` para tomar solo 5 registros
- Para que seas los 5 mas recientes puedes escribir de forma acortada el uso del método `latest()` solo que le pasas como argumento la columna por la cual haga el acomodo

> No veo la necesidad de que si por dentro de la función anónima ya estas recuperando los 5 valores mas recientes, después por fuera de nuevo trates de aplicar un ordenamiento y un limit a los resultados obtenidos.

Tu código *(que ya he probado en un ejemplo en local)*, pudiera quedar así:

```
return $this->with(['businesses' => fn($query) => $query->latest('views')->take(5)])->get();
```

Ya con la anterior consulta estarías obteniendo solo los 5 registros mas recientes asociados al modelo `Business` con ayuda del método `businesses`